# A hedge for my working place? (indoor)

Tags: hedge, office-gardening

I'm working with a computer and got the window in my back. During late afternoon and sunset, the reflection of the sun rays in my screens is really annoying. I've also got a little cabinet between me and the window. 
As I love plants I just had the idea that I simply could put a small ( ~40cm height, ~30 depth, ~1m width) hedge like plant on it. This would cover my screens from the sun rays and it would make the office greener.

The thing is that I have no idea about plants. What would be a plant which could provide the density of a hedge and can be grown inside?

I've already checked [boxwood (Buxus sempervirens)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buxus_sempervirens), which is obviously not suitable for inside.

Comment: Herr Derb, Grüezi & welcome! I fixed a few minor details for you, e.g. the plant name. Even as a seasoned SE user you should still have a look at this site’s [help] and you are of course welcome in [chat].

Answer (score 3):

A hedge might be difficult, but in a space that size, you could have 5 or 6 different potted plants, smaller ones stood in front of larger ones, to achieve the sunblocking effect you want and to create an attractive display. With regard to watering, its probably easier if you can find a tray that covers the entire area so you can stand all the pots on that to catch excess water, otherwise each one will need its own outer pot or tray. Alternatively, just choose one variety and buy enough to fill up the space.

It sounds like the area only gets afternoon sun, but there are many houseplants that don't really like any sunlight at all, so ones to look for that will be happy with some sun would be Sansevieria trifasciatia laurentii; Rhipsalis; Dizygothica elegantissima; Dracaena 'Lemon and Lime'; Dracaena studnerii; Dieffenbachia; Codiaeum iceton and for something a little more exotic, Aechmea Blue Rain or A. fasciata. There's a more complete list of suitable varieties here https://www.houseofplants.co.uk/houseplants-for-bright-and-sun.php

Answer (score 0):

You can get more out of your plants than just shade.

As the weather cools down I've lifted some plants in and ended up with a light-blocking arrangement of plants on the windowsill by my desk.  Most of them are chillies (capsicuum anuum, which despite the name aren't annual if kept out of the frost).  In the past I've had colleagues use troughs of tomato plants to similar effect, with the benefit of fresh tomatoes at lunchtime. They generally are annual, though I have seen them crop in the second year (in an office like a greenhouse)